# html---why the background can't position at the left top?

Tags: html, css

this is the site.

i use the style

```
 #idc {
 background: transparent url('../images/idbg.jpg') no-repeat left top ;
 margin:0 auto;
width: 900px;
```

}

why the image can't  position at the 0 0 place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. The image has whitespace in the top and left. See: http://newsletter.idcspy.com/images/idcbg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
background: transparent url('../images/idcbg.jpg') left top no-repeat;
```

Try that first!

Comment: Ok, try that second then, fine! Er, where'd that comment about the image whitespace go? Whoever said it is dead right...

Comment: too often I leave a comment even when posting the correct answer. Moved it to an answer...